# Make a number of dice, simulate one die

Tags: probability, dice

I was wondering about a problem for a while. Let's say a number $n$ of $6$-sided dice is given.
Is there a way to make those $n$ dice simulate just one $6$-sided die, by finding a rule so that by rolling all dice i get a number from $1$ to $6$.
To specify, the following rules are declared:

1. All dice have to be rolled at the same time.
2. If I were to roll the dice again and get the same numbers as before, the result should still be the same.
3. All dice are indistinguishable from one another. Therefore position etc. do  not matter.

Finding a solution for $2$ or $3$ dice is not a big problem (although the rule gets complicated quickly), but finding a rule depending on the number $n$ seems rather tricky, therefore does anybody know a solution to this problem?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add up all the dice and take the answer $\bmod 6$.  Add one or change $0$ to $6$.  This will give you a uniform distribution.

Comment: Wow, rather simple i guess, thank you very much!